# Как сделать динамический текст в ProgressDialog с использованием AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Пишу программу,которая прошивает Recovery.
Сделал прошивку Recovery в Background'е с использованием AsyncTask.
После нажатия кнопки выходит ProgressDialog и запускается onBackground.
Нужно сделать,чтобы после каждой операции текст в ProgressDialog менялся:

```
class TWRPFlashing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private ProgressDialog dialog;


public TWRPFlashing(MainActivity activity) {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.wait);
    dialog.setMessage("Unlocking...");
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    dialog.setMessage("Operation Complete\nReboot in Recovery after \n5 seconds");

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            sudo("reboot recovery");

        }
    }, 5000);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        sudo();
        sudo("mount -o rw,remount /system");
        sudo("mount -o rw,remount /dev");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        sudo("dd if=" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.ramdolpix.bootunlocker/files/bl_unlocked of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/devinfo");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        sudo("rm -rf /system/recovery-from-boot.p");

        sudo("rm -rf /system/wlfx0recovery-from-boot.bak0xwlf");

        sudo("rm -rf /system/bin/wlfx0install-recoverybak0xwlf");

        sudo("rm -rf /system/bin/install-recovery.sh");

        sudo("rm -rf /system/etc/install-recovery.sh");

        sudo("rm -rf /system/vendor/bin/install-recovery.sh");

        sudo("dd if=" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.ramdolpix.bootunlocker/files/twrp_unlocked.img of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/recovery");
        Thread.sleep(1500);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

К примеру после нажатия кнопки выходило сообщение "Preparing":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее вот такое окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и так далее.

И важна задержка в 1 секунду,после выполненной операции.

Comment: @danilshik что? :D

Comment: @Suvitruf устарел говорю AsyncTask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsyncTask - уже устарел , как и написали в комментариях.
Ресурсы: https://emunix.org/post/the-dark-side-of-asynctask/
https://toster.ru/q/308724
Альтернативой может быть - WorkManager из Android Architecture Components (Рекомендация от Google , поправьте , если не точно ), Service (но не для больших объемов, говорят тормозит) , Threads   и способов еще достаточно

ProgressDialog, кстати говоря - тоже
Ресурс: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373007/progressdialog-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternate-one-to-use
Советуют использовать ProgressBar

UPD:  danilshik, подумал надо добавить подробные ресурсы и про Loader :)
https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/274-urok-135-loader-loadermanager-asynctaskloader.html
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/loader.php
https://ziginsider.github.io/Loaders/
И еще немного о Service, AsyncTask и Loader http://www.ohandroid.com/android-loaders.html

Comment: вроде еще Loader можно использовать

Comment: А в статье его и упомянули)